# How can I set a unique ID for a class using a list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to set each classes ID to the x variable in my list comprehension, where ID would be 0,1,2...99.

Is this possible in python?

main function:

```
def main():
    sample_size = int(input("Enter a sample size to test"))
    people = [Person() for x in range(sample_size) Person().id = x] #<<<<<< Here
    people[0].infected = True #Infect the first person
    while True:
        input("")
        for i in range(sample_size):
            person[i].adv()
```

the class

```
import random

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.infected = False
        self.symptoms = False
        self.recovered = False
        self.dead = False
        self.days_since_infection = 0
    def inspect(self):
        print("Infected: ",self.infected)
        print("Symptoms: ",self.symptoms)
        print("Recovered: ",self.recovered)
        print("Dead: ",self.dead)
        print("Days since infection: ",self.days_since_infection)
    def adv(self):
        if not self.dead and self.infected:
            self.days_since_infection += 1
            if not self.symptoms and self.days_since_infection >= 5:
                self.symptoms = True
            elif self.days_since_infection >= 15:
                temp = random.randint(1,100)
                if temp <= 2:
                    self.dead = True
                else:
                    self.infected = False
                    self.symptoms = False
                    self.recovered = True
```

Comment: Yes, it is, please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass the id as a constructor parameter:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.infected = False
        self.symptoms = False
        self.recovered = False
        self.dead = False
        self.days_since_infection = 0

    # other methods...
```

And then use it in the list comprehension:

```
people = [Person(x) for x in range(sample_size)]
# Here ----------^
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you I cannot believe I overlooked that. Fairly new to classes. Thanks again!